# javascript [].some() in c#

Tags: c#, .net

does an equivalent of the javascript [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function exist in c#?

Comment: Eh, `Any(x => condition)`?

Comment: @L.B OP isn't asking for any off-site resource.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel he is asking for *tutorial*.

Comment: @L.B No. Where does he asks it? (Unless the question is edited which can't see)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel So you say this poor, effortless question is valid?

Comment: @L.B - Its not valid since its unclear what the OP is hoping to achieve by using this "some" (and doesn't show research effort) but it isn't asking for a tutorial

Comment: @L.B I didn't say it either. I do closevote poor questions the point is you've chosen a wrong reason for voting to close. Don't take me wrong.

Comment: I did research but its very hard to find something when you don't know what it is called. I tried to keep the question short and to the point. But it seems like that is not appreciated, how do I improve my questions in the future?

Comment: Just butting in here, I think its a valid beginner question, although a short one liner question (which hardly show effort). This is what i think is wrong with stack, it too harshly punish the beginners who don't know where to start to find anything.

Comment: I just searched [Array.Some in c#](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=array.some+in+c%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=gxfcVaOfMtDauQS-mISgCw) It takes me to `Any` method of Linq. Was that hard to find?

Comment: Generally a question that only takes up one line will rarely ever be able to show research effort (and make it clear what you're asking). Searching for "array methods c#" will get you a list of non-linq methods which will show you `Exists<T>` which is similar.. You can read [ask] for more guidelines as to what makes a good question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes there is: [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var foo = new object[10];
var some = foo.Any(x => x != null);
```